# ¿Cómo insertar los datos que tiene un DIV a la base de datos?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Estoy realizando una maquetación o diseño del cuerpo de un editor, en vez de utilizar un `textarea` estoy utilizando un `DIV` que funciona igual que un `textarea`.

En el siguiente `DIV` se inserta código html como contenido simple.

```
<div id="editor" class="editor"contenteditable></div>
```

Cómo puedo guardar los datos que contiene ese `div` a la base de datos.

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: @alanfcm Es una buena alternativa ya que el resto de input se envían por `ajax` pero de esta forma no podré validar ese div con PHP como sí lo podía hacer con el textarea, he visto que los plugin de los editores utilizan un textarea por alguna razón todo lo que se escribe en ese div se está escribiendo o se pasa la información  en ese textarea tiene alguna idea de cómo lo hacen.

Comment: en tu sistemas estas usando javascript puro o jquery u otro framework o pluging de js?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav Estoy utilizando jQuery nativamente, hasta ahora funciona muy bien, las acciones de los botones del editor. Solo me quedaría pendiente sobre esta información :(

Comment: Debes recibir el contenido del **div** con `jQuery` con html ya que `.val()` no te va a servir. ¿Que quieres pasar directamente solo el texto sin el html? Pide solo el texto: var txt = $('#editor').html().text();//valor del div en texto. Prueba a ver ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno como en tu comentario me estas diciendo que usas Jquery te muestro como podrias obtener su valor:

```js
$("#textarea").on("keyup", (e) => {

  var textDiv = $(e.target).val();
  $("#editor").html("").append(textDiv);

});
```

```css
.editor{
border:1px solid;
height:150px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h3>Tipea para ir mostrandolo en el div</h3>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<h3>Div editable</h3>
<div id="editor" class="editor" contenteditable></div>
```

Si te fijas si quieres obtener el texto usas el **.text()** o si es el contenido html usas **.html()**, en el evento click que hice es donde tu haces tu ajax pero la idea de obtener los valores alli la tienes, luego tu base de datos dependiendo de cual sea usaria un tipo de dato para que te deje guardar grandes cantidades de texto el html, en oracle por ejemplo el tipo de dato del campo seria **BLOB**, espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav disculpa También puedo reemplazar el button por un textarea o no.

Comment: Quieres el textare para sustraer su contenido al div o viceversa?

Comment: cuando no se activan los plugin `js` no se muestra el editor con sus botones etc solo muestra un simple textarea, ese mismo textarea permanece enmascarado se podría decir porque todo lo que se escribe en ese div, el textarea recibe o guarda esos datos. No sé exactamente como funciona, no sé si me comprendes de que editor habló, es uno similar al que escribes tus preguntas o respuestas aquí solo que yo lo estoy realizando de manera más optimizada y simple sin plugin de terceros.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta con un textarea, alli el textarea recibe el valor que capture del div, ahora si el flujo es inverso primero captura el valor del textarea y luego lo setas al div. @Stevin

Comment: Se acerca a lo que tenía en mente, pero en el textarea debe recibir todo el código HTML generado en el div editable, se recuerda que es un editor, por lo tanto los datos a ingresar a la base de datos debe insertarse con el código HTML que el editor haya añadido, esa parte lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera http://jsfiddle.net/02fvzn5b/11/ pero no cumple con las funciones deseadas, entiendo que los botones que has agregado es parte de demostración del ejemplo dado, pero yo necesito que esos datos se pases automáticamente al mismo tiempo

Comment: Que se vaya escribiendo en el div editable, en tiempo real, sin la ayuda de ningún botón para pasar esa información. Lo cual he eliminado los botones dejando solo las funciones, pero no se pasan los valores que tiene el div editable al textarea puedes observarlo en ejecución http://jsfiddle.net/02fvzn5b/11/

Comment: @Stevin modifique el codigo, lo que hace es cuando vas tipeando en el textarea se va visualizando en el div editable, puedes colocar un html como <b>hola</b> para probar

Comment: Gracias :) Ya lo había solucionado